# Intellij not support create a web.xml checkbox

Tags: intellij-idea, web.xml

I can not choose to 'create a web.xml' while creating a web project with Java.

[image: I can not choose to 'create a web.xml' while creating a web project with Java.]

Answer (score 0):

Issue should be fixed in 2018.1 and neares 2017.3 update: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-182976